# В Kotlin переменные хранят сами объекты или ссылки на них?

Tags: kotlin

Есть класс Engine, в одном из методов мы создаем объект являющийся экземпляром этого класса. Затем мы передаем этот экземпляр в поле другого объекта. Тут и возникает вопрос мы передали копию Engine или ссылку на него, т.е. если мы в изначальном методе изменим состояние Engine, то в другом объекте, в который мы передали Engine, его состояние изменится или нет?

Comment: что мешает сделать и проверить?

Answer (score 1):

Копией передаются только примитивы, и только если интерпретируются как примитивы. То есть если Int при компиляции превратился в java-вский int, то он копируется. Если в Integer, то передается ссылка. Все остальные объекты передаются ссылкой

Comment: Нет. Написал на kotlin что-то вроде `a = Integer(1); b = a; a = Integer(2); println(b)`. Проверил онлайн - тип транслируется в java как `Integer`, но в консоль выводит 1. Т.е. даже в вашем случае передалось значение, НЕ ссылка

Comment: Простите, но ваш пример категорически неправильный. Во-первых, класс интеджер неизменяемый, то есть вы не можете изменить значение внутри уже созданного объекта. Во-вторых, а чего вы ждали? Создаем обьект интеджер, его ссылку кладем в а. Создаем переменную б и кладем в нее ссылку на тот же интеджер. Теперь неважно что вы делаете с переменной а, в б лежит ссыька на первый интеджер. Так будет работать для чего угодно

Comment: Наверное вы хотели получить что-то такое: val a = intArrayOf(1); val b = a; b[0]=2; println(a[0]). Тут выведется два. Но с неизменяемым классом такое поведение неполучит, в этом и есть из прелесть. Потому котлин для них обзовелся даже отдельным ключевым словом data class

Comment: Если конкретнее - есть разые области памяти. Конкретно нам интересны стэк и куча. Если вы создаете примитив - он создастся в стэке, куча не затронется. Если объект - он создастся в куче, а ссылка на него ляжет в стек. Опкратор копировпния обычно работает тол ко с данными из стека, потому для примитива создается полная копия, а для объектов копируется только ссылка. Это важно знать чтоб ловить утечки памяти и понимать как работает сборщик мусора, но пока у вас учебные проекты можно сильно не запариваться. А вот изменяемы классы типа списков могут повлиять на поведение, тут надо разбираться

Comment: сори, да, меня что-то переклинило. Я рассчитывал, что a - указатель на некоторое значение, b - указатель на переменную a. На самом деле походу b - указатель на тот же адрес памяти, на который указывает a и при изменении a b продолжит указывать на старую область памяти